# MarkLogic - Search based on the path of JSON object (without using path range index)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic : 9.0-6.2

We have a JSON document as below, in customer entity.

```
"CustomerInfo": {
  "IdInfo": {
     "CustomerId":"12345"
  }, 
  "PartyRltp": {
      "CustomerId":"45678"
  }
}
```

My need is to search the document based on CustomerId at the specific path CustomerInfo.IdInfo.CustomerId

So if I search for "12345", the above document should be returned. But if I search with "45678", the above document should NOT be returned.

I created path range index and used cts.pathRangeQuery('/CustomerInfo/IdInfo/CustomerId','=', '12345'). However, realized that path range indexes are very expensive, so looking for a way to achieve without path range index.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery):

```
cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery(
  'IdInfo',
  cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(
    'CustomerId',
    '12345'
  )
)
```

HTH!

Comment: Be aware that this query will not work unfiltered :)

Comment: Good point, but you may not need filtering. Enable both word positions and element word positions to make the scope query accurate without filtering. And if CustomerId never contains spaces, nor interpunction and such, you likely won't need filtered searches at all.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did not further test it but I think you need to enable element value positions instead of element word positions.

Comment: The word positions are for the scope query (it is mentioned on that docs page), but you are probably right that, since above uses a value query in a scoped context, you'd also need element value positions enabled. https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.plan is your friend with that..